# Create a variable inside of call method with shape depending on batch size

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a recurrent model, which feeds back previous outputs to the input layer(s) of the model together with the new input. To consider multiple time steps, I use a buffer which stores these previous outputs. To speed things up, the buffer of course saves the outputs for the entire batch. This is working fine, until I hit the last batch of my training data, which will in general have less samples than the target number.

I currently try to adjust the size of my buffer according to the input shape, however, I run into considerable trouble getting this to work. An error is caused by the concatenations occurring, which raises an error for the last batch due to incompatible first dimensions.

More precisely, what I do is

```
def call(self, x):
    if self.bypass:
        return x

    decoded = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=tf.shape(x)[1])
    for i in tf.range(tf.shape(x)[1]):
        xslice = x[:,i,:]
        xin = tf.concat((xslice, self.buffer), axis=1)
        encoded = self.ls(self.l2(self.l1(xin)))

        if self.save_encoded:
            self.encoded_list.append(encoded.numpy())

        if self.quantizer is not None:
            encoded = tf.py_function(self.quantize, [encoded], tf.float32)

        decin = tf.concat([encoded, self.buffer], axis=1)
        y = self.l5(self.l4(self.l3(decin)))
        decoded = decoded.write(i,y)
        i += 1
        self.buffer.assign(tf.concat([y, self.buffer[:, :-self.shape[0]]], axis=1))


    tmp = tf.transpose(decoded.stack(),[1,0,2])
    return tmp
```

Currently, making things very inconvenient, I set the buffer shape before training via

```
def SetupBuffer(self, batch_size, input_dim, ht):
    self.buffer = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(batch_size, input_dim * ht), dtype=tf.float32), trainable=False)
```

However, when I call SetupBuffer within the call method of my model I receive an error. That is, if I call

```
self.SetupBuffer(tf.shape(x)[0], self.shape[0], self.ht)
```

within the call method, I get the error

> in call       self.SetupBuffer(tf.shape(x)[0], self.shape[0], self.ht)
> in SetupBuffer  *
> self.buffer = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(batch_size, input_dim * >ht), dtype=tf.float32), trainable=False)

> ValueError: Argument `initial_value` (Tensor("FRAE_enc_left/zeros:0", shape=(None, 16), dtype=float32)) could not be lifted out of a `tf.function`. (Tried to create variable with name='None'). To avoid this error, when constructing `tf.Variable`s inside of `tf.function` you can create the `initial_value` tensor in a `tf.init_scope` or pass a callable `initial_value` (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`). Please file a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.

> Call arguments received by layer "FRAE_enc_left" (type FRAE):
> • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 8), dtype=float32)

Unfortunately, simply using a subsection of self.buffer, i.e. doing something like self.buffer[current_batch_size, :], does not work either within the call method.

Is there a way to do what I want? It would make my (surrounding) code much simpler, if the size of my buffer adapted automatically to the size of the current batch.